# Seaborn -- map diagonal with asymmetric axes

Tags: python, seaborn

I have some data where it makes sense to plot certain, but not all variables against each other and in particular where it only makes sense to plot KDEs for certain variables. This seems, generally, like a good use case for `seaborn`'s  `PairGrid`. However, I cannot use `sb.PairGrid.map_diag` for the variables for which I do want a KDE when it seems like I ought to be.

The following code works as I imagine it would:

```py
import seaborn as sb
import pandas as pd
iris=sb.load_dataset('iris')
pgiris = sb.PairGrid(data=iris,
    x_vars=['sepal_width','petal_width','sepal_length'],
    y_vars=['sepal_width','petal_width','sepal_length'])
pgiris.map_diag(sb.kdeplot)
```

Let's imagine, though, that it  *doesn't* make sense to plot `sepal_length` on both axes:

```py
pgiris=sb.PairGrid(data=iris,x_vars=['sepal_width','petal_width','sepal_length'],y_vars=['sepal_width','petal_width'])
pgiris.map_diag(sb.kdeplot)
```

Under `seaborn 0.9.0` and `python3.6.7`, this throws a `TypeError` for reasons I do not understand-- a cursory reading suggests that it does not assign any axes its `diag_axes` attribute. Oddly, the `map_offdiag` methods seem to work just fine, so I don't think that this is  intended to not work for asymmetric pairgrids.

How do I properly map functions to diagonal elements of asymmetric `PairGrid`s?

Comment: Does not seem like this is allowed in seaborn's code.  It works with `map_offdiag` because that calls a numpy method to identify the indices of the lower-triangle and upper-triangle of an (n,m) (not necessarily square) array.  And that does not happen in `map_diag`.

Comment: After poking around in the code it looks like `seaborn` is mishandling this use case : `diag_axes` is initialized as `None` in the class `__init__` method and only assigned if the grid matrix is square *and* `diag_axes` isn't assigned. But there's no `else` clause-- if the matrix isn't square then it simply tries to run on ahead without assigning `diag_axes` to anything.

ETA: That said, I'm not sure if `seaborn`'s authors intend the user to be able to do this in a different way (that is, without going to each subplot with different explicit instructions).